# Is $1.9999...$ equal to $2$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

A rather simple question I suppose, however I have not seen a discussion on this topic on stackexchange as of yet. In fact, when I was in high school I once used the following 'proof' to prove to my teacher that $1.9999... = 2$, where the dots indicate an 'infinite' number of decimal $9$'s:

$$x = 1.99999...$$

$$10x = 19.9999...$$

$$9x = 19.9999... - 1.9999... = 18$$

$$x = 2$$

$$1.9999... = 2$$

My teacher, who has a Masters degree in Mathematics in university, then told me that infinity is a tricky concept in mathematics and that this needn't work the way it seems to. Now, many many years later, being an econometrics student myself, I have found myself thinking about this 'proof'. To me, it seems that claiming a number to have an 'infinite' number of decimal $9$'s is faulty in itself; it would be much more logical to state that the number of $9$'s approaches infinity and as a result, that $1.9999...$ is asymptotically equal to $2$, but not equal to $2$.

However, when Googling this question I am overwhelmed with the number of results where people claim that it is in fact exactly, literally, equal: that $1.9999... = 2$ is undisputably true. As a result I am now unsure whether it is or is not true.

Thus, is $1.9999... = 2$?

Comment: Short story, yes. You may not find a discussion about $1.999...=2$, but you will surely find one on $0.999...=1$

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I'm not fully satisfied with the answers on that post but I do see that it's been discussed before.

Comment: Step one: Define the meaning of the sequence of seven symbols "$1.9999\ldots$"